# iPhone 4s/ios5 next button skipping to top of page /also not firing change event

Tags: iphone, ios4, mobile-safari, ios5

My web page has several dropdowns, users can click through the next button to select values in different drop downs. We are seeing a weird behavior, when clicking the next button after selecting an option, safari skips to the top of the page.

Our site is not live yet, i found similar issue in a e.com goto a e.com select any product and click on the quantity dropdown and click next button, the safari skips to the top of the page. This is happening only with iPhone 4s. I noticed this behaviour is in iOS 5.

Also noticed that clicking next button doesn't fire change event.

Any help to resolve this is greatly appreciated.

I noticed the same problem in many websites [edmunds - used appraise it, jcp product page, gap etc..] only in ios5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda resolved the jumping by adding javascript to disable all other elements, except the current one. Whenever the user clicks on a dropdown, the asset picker will display and force the user to click the done button, thus the change event will be fired and skipping to top of the page is also prevented.

This is not an optimal solution, still if you want a dirty and quick fix you can try this. It works. I'm doing all these fun only if mobile iOS is greater than 5.